# 疑似乱数生成のアルゴリズムについて

Tags: javascript, random

JavaScriptで線形合同法などのアルゴリズムを使って乱数を作成したいと考えています。線形合同法は調べたら出てくるのですが、できればたくさんのアルゴリズムを使って生成したいので、線形合同法以外の乱数生成アルゴリズムを教えてください。

Comment: 単に「乱数生成アルゴリズム」の話であれば、検索するだけで色々な方法が出てくるかと思います。それらを調べても分からないことがある場合、例えばJavaScriptでの書き方に困ってる等で質問をより詳しく書いておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

検索では「たくさん」は見つけられなかったので、列挙でよければWikipediaの[List of random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators)を紹介しておきます。

実装方法含めて「たくさん」回答しろというのはさすがに無茶なのでそれぞれ個別に調べてください。